# using a stored procedure in a mysql select

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm an sql newbie and I'm confused about using stored procedures.

What I have are two tables, a users table and a registrations table with a one to many relationship between the two. In simplest terms, I want to output a list of users with a count of their registrations. I know how to do this with a left join. However, the select on the registrations is getting somewhat messy and I'd like to have it be cleaner.

What I would really like is "select users.name, getCount(users.id) from users" and have all the logic for counting the registrations in the getCount stored procedure. But I'm not finding any docs for doing it this way. Is this possible or does getCount go into a left join or is this just not what stored procedures are for?

Comment: You would be better off using a view than a stored procedure (actually, you would need a function - an SP that returns a value)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a stored procedure in a SELECT statement. But you can use a function. Some things you cannot do in a FUNCTION.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test (id INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE get_count INT;

..
logic to set get_count
..

RETURN get_count;
END$$
```